# To call a controller method & stay on same view

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am learning spring mvc framework. I would to like to know is there any way to pass data(request object & String) to controller & return an object without reloading the view.

Right now when i return the object it reloads the view & all previously loaded values are lost.

```
public ModelAndView getSelectedApp( HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView mav, @RequestParam(value="application") String appName){
    System.out.println("hello");
    List<ApplicationBean> apps = (List<ApplicationBean>)request.getServletContext().getAttribute("applications");
    ApplicationBean application = null;
    for (ApplicationBean applicationBean : apps) {
        if(applicationBean.getAppName().equals(appName)){
            application= applicationBean;
        }
    }
    //ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("application", application);
    mav.setViewName("home");;
    //mav.setView(new Redi);
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What have you tried and why doesn't it work? Provide code examples and try to point out where you think the problem is.

Comment: You need to make an ajax call (async post request), for example with [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to render a ModelAndAttribute from the Controller. Let´s say entity A, then you have to put into a form.

```
     <form:form id="formId" method="POST" modelAttribute="A">
         <form:hidden id="aId" path="A.id"/>
    </form:form> 
    <button id="buttonId" type="button" onclick="saveA()">Save</button>
```

Then you need to create the submitA con javascript method and do an Ajax call to the controller serializing formId

```
  function saveA() {
    $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    url: 'url',
    data: $('#formId').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        //Congratulation you did your first ajax call.
    }
  });
  }
```

On your controller you need a method to wait for the A object

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/saveA.do", method =          RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public final void saveA(@PathVariable(A a) {}
```

Comment: Clicking the button will submit the form and reload the view. You will need to cancel the default behavior using `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: No, it wont button is not type submit.

Comment: how to pass data to the controller & return data from it. I an sorry for silly things, I am new to this framework

Comment: Paul, it does not have to be a submit button explicitly. Having any kind of button can trigger a submit. http://jsfiddle.net/uChZ7/

Comment: @Bart trust me is not happening, only javascript method is invoked and no submit is done.

Comment: @garima I provide you good enough code to start, don't have too much knowledges about a framework is not excuse to do not study a little.

Comment: @garima MKYong is a very good teacher http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: @Paul I must be living in a parallel universe where adding a button to a form submits the form regardless.

Comment: You´re welcome. If the answer was good enough remember to vote and put the response as finish

Comment: @Bart sorry my man you right, my fault I did not notice that I put the button inside the form. I made the correction on the code right away!. Thanks